# In ansible variable for hosts from vars_prompt no longer accepted

Tags: ansible

I've upgraded ansible to v2.6.2. After upgrade ansible variable for hosts from vars_prompt no longer accepted.

```
---
- hosts: "{{ hosts }}"
  vars_prompt:
    - name: "hosts"
      private: no

  tasks:
  - name: touch file
    command: touch /home/tomcat/a
```

I'm getting below error

```
ERROR! The field 'hosts' has an invalid value, which includes an undefined variable. The error was: 'hosts' is undefined

The error appears to have been in '/home/tomcat/test.yml': line 2, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

---
- hosts: "{{ hosts }}"
  ^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes.  Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:

    with_items:
      - {{ foo }}

Should be written as:

    with_items:
      - "{{ foo }}"
```

Any suggestion on this?

Comment: it was working in ansible v2.4

Comment: Indeed it works in 2.4 but no more in 2.6. I don't know it is deliberated or not. better is to report to developers on github. I find this possibility quite interesting actually.

Comment: It seems to be reported quite some time ago https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/37984

Comment: @techraf I think the duplicate can be removed for this question, as the question is valid.

Comment: No, I don't think so. This is the same problem and the answers under the dup-target, particularly the accepted one is applicable to this question, as a reliable way of achieving the goal. In fact, it should be the other way round: the code from this question should have been posted as an answer there (when it was still working, and when it will again), so that the knowledge is collected and not dispersed.